Google API Error 400 When fetching emails using Service Account

Is it possible to fetch all the emails of all the employees in the company using a service account?
Am I missing any permissions or scopes?

I am desperate to resolve this task, so I hope to get the answer here.
I set up the service account in my GSuit and my goal is to get all the emails and calendars of all the users in my company.
Steps, that I have done:
Created a new API app
Enable access to APIs
Enabled API apps Google Calendar API, Gmail API, Admin SDK API, Google People API, Contacts API
OAuth consent screen. Internal. Add scopes:
/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
mail.google.com/
/auth/profile.emails.read
/auth/gmail.readonly
/auth/user.emails.read
/auth/userinfo.email
Created Service Account. Granted permissions "Service Account Token Creator", Viewer.
Security > API Controls > Domain-wide Delegation to my Service Account client ID:
mail.google.com,
/auth/contacts,
/auth/gmail.readonly,
/auth/userinfo.email,
auth/userinfo.profile,
auth/admin.directory.user,
auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
I can get Users but not emails.
It throws the error:
The service gmail has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Precondition check failed.
[400] Errors [ Message[Precondition check failed.] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] Domain[global] ]
Google.GoogleApiException: The service gmail has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. The precondition check failed.
And my code is simple as:
string[] scopes = { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };

GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(keyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
        .CreateWithUser("my service account email")
        .CreateScoped(scopes);
}

var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Your Application Name",
});

// Call the API to get users
var users = service.Users.List();
users.Customer = "My company's CustomerID";

var response = users.Execute();
var userList = response.UsersValue;

var serviceGmail = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Your Application Name",
});

foreach (var user in userList)
{
    var request = serviceGmail.Users.Messages.List(user.Id);
    ListMessagesResponse emails = request.Execute();
    var messages = emails.Messages;  
}

I followed the oficial documentation and checked out tons of the stach overflow articles.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
